# Asp.Net jquery CRUD

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, crud

in asp.net soloution i have a html table like this:

```
 <table class="table" id="example1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>News Name</th>

                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     <asp:Repeater ID="gdvNews" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewsID") %></td>
                        <td class="font-bold text-left"><%#   DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href='<%# Eval("NewsID", "News_Edit.aspx? NewsId={0}") %>' class="btn small bg-blue-alt tooltip-button" data-placement="top"  title="Edit">
                                <i class="glyph-icon icon-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn small bg-red tooltip-button" data-placement="top" title="Remove">
                                <i class="glyph-icon icon-remove"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

i fill repeater with list of news in asp.net c# code.

is there any way to get database value of one row in a table with jquery or json ? and then show it in asp.net textbox or delete that row ?

Comment: Yes you can. You have to create class of your table. Then with ajax (jquery or pagemethods)  you can get data or you can send delete or update command.

Comment: IS pagemethods better than jquery?

Comment: I use pagemethods more because is more simple and less things to write :)

Comment: and in security which is better?

Comment: Look if someone with good knowledge wants to harm you, he/she will... believe me. I do not know for security.